# Return Function description as string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, introspection

Is it possible to output the content of a user-defined function as a string (not the enumeration, but just the function call):

Function:

```
def sum(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Function content as a string:

```
"sum(), return x+y"
```

The inspect function might have worked but it seems to be for just python 2.5 and below?

Comment: Why `addition()` and not `addition(self)`?

Comment: `inspect` is not for Python 2.5 or below; where did you read that? The `inspect` module is alive and kicking in the latest Python releases.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Right, so why `sum()` and not `sum(x, y)`?

Comment: And what should happen for functions with more than one line of code?

Comment: Just and example actually. Doesn't really matter. Would that make a difference? If I define a function where I have to pass in parameters, then sum(x,y) would matter.

Comment: If the function has more than one line of code, it should print the entire thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`inspect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) works just fine for retrieving source code, this is not limited to older Python versions.

Provided the source is available (e.g. the function is not defined in C code or the interactive interpreter, or was imported from a module for which only the `.pyc` bytecode cache is available), then you can use:

```
import inspect
import re
import textwrap

def function_description(f):
    # remove the `def` statement.
    source = inspect.getsource(f).partition(':')[-1]
    first, _, rest = source.partition('\n')
    if not first.strip():  # only whitespace left, so not a one-liner
        source = rest
    return "{}(), {}".format(
        f.__name__,
        textwrap.dedent(source))
```

Demo:

```
>>> print open('demo.py').read()  # show source code
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

def mean(x, y): return sum(x, y) / 2

def factorial(x):
    product = 1
    for i in xrange(1, x + 1):
        product *= i
    return product

>>> from demo import sum, mean, factorial
>>> print function_description(sum)
sum(), return x + y

>>> print function_description(mean)
mean(), return sum(x, y) / 2

>>> print function_description(factorial)
factorial(), product = 1
for i in xrange(1, x + 1):
    product *= i
return product
```

Comment: I get the following error:     raise IOError('could not get source code')
IOError: could not get source code

Comment: @BlackHat: then there is no source code to retrieve. Did you define the function in the interactive interpreter? Then there is no source code left to inspect.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you.